# How do i give an appimage access to my microphone?

Tags: microphone, appimage

I'm trying to give [Chiaki](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ethestr4ng3r/chiaki) my microphone to allow my friends to hear me when we go into ps4 chat. it seems there is no setting inside of Chiaki to enable a microphone. any help is appreciated. Here is the download file for Chiaki https://github.com/thestr4ng3r/chiaki/releases/download/v1.3.0/Chiaki-v1.3.0-Linux-x86_64.AppImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not implemented in chiaki unfortunately.

This has nothing to do about permissions, it is just not supported by the app currently.